# Regex match words, but not when the entire string is matched

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have this regex now:

```
((\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b)\s*(?!.*\2))+
```

This matches the predefined words, up until a word is already used (if any). See below (matches in **bold**) for several examples:

1. **Example** Overflow **Test Overflow**
2. **Example Overflow Test**
3. Just an **Example Overflow**
4. **Example** another **Overflow**

This is doing what I ask it to, but I want to special case the 2nd example (Example Overflow Test). If the entire string is matched (from start to end), I don't want to match the first word anymore. So 2. should instead match "Example **Overflow Test**". My original regex has many more words, so I'd like to avoid repeating these and instead refer back to the same capture group similar to how I already check if a word is already used before.

Comment: Does it mean you just do not want a match to happen at the start of string? Add `(?!^)` at the start of the pattern.

Comment: Not always, let me clarify my example @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You want one word before the key word and everything to the end : "\w+\s+Overflow.*".

Comment: I made a mistake with the $ character, this isn't always the case as it can also match within a sentence, see my updated description.

Comment: But the `Example` in the first sentence will be found, too, why is it not bold?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to edit that one, should be OK now.

Comment: I do not think you can avoid repetition here. `(?!^(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)\s*)+$)(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\2\b)\s*)+` seems to work. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4I0AWk/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot! I think it's indeed very difficult to avoid repetition. Your sample seems to work OK, I will probably add some helper to generate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to lay a restriction on a part of a match (you still want to match a part of a string if there is a matching part), you can use something like

```
(?!^(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)\s*)+$)(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\2\b)\s*)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4I0AWk/4).

The `(?!^(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)\s*)+$)` negative lookahead cancels the match if the word from the list is matched at the start and the match spans till string end at that position. Note the changed backreference numbers and the additional word boundaries around the backreferences to avoid getting partial matches in the lookahead.

In C#, you can [define the repeating patterns with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994445/3832970) and reuse it inside the string literal where you define the regex.

Comment: Just checked with all my values and this seems to work just fine, thanks again 

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: To work on Windows text files, you must add `\r?` before `$`, like this: `(?!^(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\1\b) *)+\r?$)(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\2\b) *)+` (Regex101 uses `\n` as line breaks).

Comment: @PoulBak Only if the strings are multiline strings and the regex must be run on each line. Then, the `\r?` is not enough, `\s` must be restricted to match horizontal whitespaces only. In this case, it should look like `(?m)(?!^(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)[\p{Zs}\t]*)+\r?$)(?:\b(Example|Overflow|Test)\b(?!.*\b\2\b)[\p{Zs}\t]*)+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Oh, I see now that here you have `\s`, but at regex101 you used a space, not `\s` - that seems to work.